# When using ACTION_GET_CONTENT on kitkat, apps registered with Storage Access Framework is also getting listed

Tags: android, storage-access-framework

On kitkat, I am using ACTION_GET_CONTENT to list the apps supporting Images. But in the Chooser UI, I can see two sections. The top section is listing apps registered with Storage Access Framework (SAF) and the bottom section of list shows apps registered for intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT.

First, I want to know is this working in correct way? If yes, then the apps which are registered to both are seen twice. is there a way to filter them in one of the list. For example, if an app is seen in top section (registered to SAF), it should not be seen in bottom section (registered to ACTION_GET_CONTENT).

Comment: "First, I want to know is this working in correct way?" -- AFAIK, yes. "If yes, then the apps which are registered to both are seen twice" -- such apps are buggy. The documentation specifically states that apps should support either the `DOCUMENT` actions *or* `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` for a given device, based on API level (see the "xx" in [the instructions for writing a document provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html#custom)).

Comment: @CommonsWare.. thanks for your reply. I read the document you shared in the link and what you said looks to be correct. If you can put your comment as answer, I will go ahead and accept it as correct answer. But is there no workaround by which I can list these buggy apps in only one list from inside my app?

Comment: That's the reason why I did not make it an answer. I don't think that there is a workaround, but I cannot rule it out.

Comment: @CommonsWare The doc is not enough clear. I mean in the first section they said: "ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is not intended to be a replacement for ACTION_GET_CONTENT. The one you should use depends on the needs of your app." So if they are mutually exclusive I can't design my client app using one or the other I **must** use SAF on 19+ but this kind of constraint is not reported at all instead the doc says I can decide what action I want according to my use cases. It's really another mess by Google.